# Getting HDMI working on Inspiron 15R N5110?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, hdmi

I installed Windows 8.1 on my Laptop which had Windows 7 when I bought it. After installing Windows 8.1 and installing the drivers [Drivers & Downloads page](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/ServiceTag/19WCJR1) I still haven't got the HDMI to work. If someone could help me, that would be great

Comment: So you have install the Intel HD drivers correct?  What driver version did you install exactly?  Don't link me to a non-English website.

Comment: I am this user, could you link me to that exact driver? I don't know if I installed it correctly :/

Comment: @Jeggy - You can't really install a drive incorrectly. I can't link to an exact driver since I don't know what hardware you have exactly.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting an external display to your HDMI port on the computer, right click on your desktop and click 'Screen Resolution'. If there is a grey screen there, click it and change 'Multiple Displays: Disconnect this display' to 'Multiple Displays: extend desktop to this display'. You may need to also try holding the `Fn` key (next to left `ctrl`) and tapping the display key, which I think on your computer is F1.